# Get if element is hidden or inside hidden container

Tags: jquery, angularjs

**I'm working on this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/ba8ws3t3/)**

From the "start" input, I'd like to focus the next empty input on blur. 
Each input has a "next" attribute so that I can create a chain. I'll then go trough this chain until I find an empty input and focus it.

```
<input id="a" next="b" value="value" />
<input id="b" next="c" value="value" />
<input id="c" next="d" />
<input id="d" next="a" value="value" />


while($('#' + _next).val() != ''){
    _next = $('#' + _next).attr('next');
}
$('#' + _next).focus();
```

The only problem is when the parent input is hidden (with ngHide directive). This prevents me from focusing the children inputs.

So I would like to know, is there a fast way to know if an element is hidden or inside a hidden parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) you can do

```
$('element').is(':hidden')
```

or

```
$('element').parent().is(':hidden')
```

or if you have a target selector

```
$('element').closest('.target').is(':hidden')
```

Comment: But what if I have <parent><parent><parent><INPUT></parent></parent></parent>, should I test each one?? Isn't there a faster selector?

Comment: @LucaDeNardi, use closest() like in my updated answer

Comment: It looks like element.is(':hidden') is evaluated to true even if one of the parents is hidden! Awesome, thank you!